# Error with Laravel authentication

Tags: authentication, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I am trying to implement authentication in my application, when I post the login form this error is returned in my browser:

[image]

I have no idea what this error means, where it occurs, or how to fix it.

This is my signin function in my authentication controller that handles all logins:

```
public function signin()
    {
        // validate the info, create rules for the inputs
        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
            'password' => 'required|min:6' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
        );

        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('/authentication')
                ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
                ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
        } else {

            // create our user data for the authentication
            $user = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password')
            );

            // attempt to do the login
            if (Auth::attempt($user)) {

                // validation successful!
                // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
                // return Redirect::to('secure');
                // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
                return Redirect::to('dashboard.index');

            } else {

                // validation not successful, send back to form
                return Redirect::to('/authentication')
                    ->with('failed', 'Incorrect email / password!');

            }

        }
    }
```

This is my User model:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent{

    // MASS ASSIGNMENT -------------------------------------------------------
    // define which attributes are mass assignable (for security)
    protected $fillable = array('email','school_id','role_id','activation_key','reset_key','login_status','account_status');

    // LINK THIS MODEL TO OUR DATABASE TABLE ---------------------------------
    protected $table = 'users';

    // DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS --------------------------------------------------
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Role');
    }

    public function schools() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Institution');
    }

    public function lectures() {
        return $this->hasOne('Lecturer');
    }

    public function students() {
        return $this->hasOne('Student');
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your user model to the question?

Comment: Added it, please check it out for me. :)

Comment: What if you have your User model implement UserInterface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at Laravel's default `User` model:

```
class User extends Eloquent ...
```

so far so good

```
... implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

Oooops looks like you're missing something ;)

Also the two traits are not unimportant.

Here's how it *should* look like:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    // MASS ASSIGNMENT -------------------------------------------------------
    // define which attributes are mass assignable (for security)
    protected $fillable = array('email','school_id','role_id','activation_key','reset_key','login_status','account_status');

    // [the rest of your model]
```

Comment: It says now that "UserInterface not found", sorry for the late reply.

Comment: It works now, i was missing some "use" statements at the top of my code, than you very much. :)